# Retrieve Menu name for nav_menu_item

Tags: menus

Given a `nav_menu_item` object, how would I determine the name of the Menu it is associated with?

I have a couple menus defined in my theme, as well as, a `nav_menu_css_class` filter.  Inside the filter, I only want to add classes to one of the menus.  If I can dynamically pull the menu name using the `$item` variable I can make sure I'm only acting on a specific menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument passed to the filter are the `$args` used for `wp_nav_menu`:

```
function wpse_147499_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args ) {
     print_r( $args );
     exit;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_147499_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 3 );
```

...which gives you:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [menu] => 
    [container] => 
    [container_class] => 
    [container_id] => 
    [menu_class] =>
    [menu_id] => 
    [echo] => 1
    [fallback_cb] => 
    [before] => 
    [after] => 
    [link_before] => 
    [link_after] => 
    [items_wrap] =>
    [depth] => 0
    [walker] => 
    [theme_location] =>
)
```

Obviously the values of these vary, and never assume that one will always be non-empty - but hopefully you should be able to differentiate between menus.

Comment: Thank You!!  This worked perfectly.  I'll come back and mark as the accepted answer once my rep has increased.

Comment: @CodeKing please revisit **all** your questions and accept answers that should be accepted answers. You don't need any reputation to accept an answer to your questions. You also gain reputation for accepting an answer to your questions and there is a badge as well. Thank you